increase vector density in python with nc data
I mapped the wind vectors using the 850 mbar gridded wind data that I extracted from the NOAA site. My problem is: the vectors are very compact and I want to reduce their density. Thank you very much if you can help me.
from netCDF4 import Dataset as NetCDFFile 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
import numpy as np'
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib import rcParams
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11,9)) #(figsize=(WIDTH_SIZE,HEIGHT_SIZE))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111 )
ax.set_title('(a2)' , size=12 , x=.5, y=.98 ,fontweight='bold') 
nc1 = NetCDFFile('E:/cycle-of-Mjo/NOAA/nc/u850b1.nc')
nc2 = NetCDFFile('E:/cycle-of-Mjo/NOAA/nc/v850b1.nc')
lat = nc1.variables['lat'][:]
lon = nc1.variables['lon'][:]
U1 = nc1.variables['uwnd'][:]
V1 = nc2.variables['vwnd'][:]
map = Basemap(projection='merc', lon_0 =0 , lat_0 =-20 ,llcrnrlon=0., llcrnrlat=-20. ,urcrnrlon=360.          urcrnrlat=61.,resolution='i' ,suppress_ticks=False)
lat_ticks=np.arange(np.ceil(-20.0),int(61.0),20)
lon_ticks=np.arange(np.ceil(0.0),int(360.0),50)
lon_ticks_proj, _=map(lon_ticks, np.zeros(len(lon_ticks)))
_, lat_ticks_proj=map(np.zeros(len(lat_ticks)), lat_ticks)
ax.set_xticks(lon_ticks_proj)
ax.set_yticks(lat_ticks_proj)
plt.tick_params(labelleft=False, labelbottom=False , axis='both',which='major')
map.drawcoastlines()
map.drawcounties() 
parallels = np.arange(-20.,61.,20.)
meridians = np.arange(0,360.,50.)
map.drawparallels(lat_ticks,labels=[1,0,0,0],fontsize=10 , dashes=(0,1), fontweight='bold' )
map.drawmeridians(lon_ticks,labels=[0,0,0,0],fontsize=10, dashes=(0,1) , fontweight='bold')
lons,lats= np.meshgrid(lon,lat)
x,y = map(lons,lats)
map.quiver(x, y,U1[0,:,:],V1[0,:,:])
plt.savefig('C:/Users/user/Desktop/project/mjo anomalies/SST/vector.png')
plt.show()

enter image description here

Welcome! Please, as a new user here, start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Point is, there are several issues with your question. Actually, you're not even asking a question, which is one of the issues.
